# Is there any way to inherit method signature with util.promisify on typescript?

Tags: javascript, node.js, typescript

From v8.0.0 Node provides [util.promisify()](https://nodejs.org/dist/latest-v8.x/docs/api/util.html#util_util_promisify_original) API. Now I'm trying to convert some callback-style method into async/await style.
On typescript, `util.promisify()` may not inherit method signature:

```
import fs = require('fs');

export namespace AsyncFs {
    export const lstat = util.promisify(fs.lstat);
    // there's no method signature, only shows as "Function"
}
```

Although we can add new signature for each method...

```
export const lstat = util.promisify(fs.lstat) as (path: string | Buffer) => fs.Stats;
```

So I'm looking for a good way to inherit signatures automatically. Is it possible? Do you have any good ideas?

Thanks.

Comment: By "inherit", you mean *infer*?

Answer (score 1):

If not handled by TS internally, then you will likely have to define the type for `util.promisify()` yourself doing something similar to [what they do for Bluebird's promisify() static function in DefinitelyTyped](https://github.com/DefinitelyTyped/DefinitelyTyped/blob/master/types/bluebird/index.d.ts#L632-L6368).

```
  static promisify<T>(func: (callback: (err: any, result: T) => void) => void, options?: Bluebird.PromisifyOptions): () => Bluebird<T>;
  static promisify<T, A1>(func: (arg1: A1, callback: (err: any, result: T) => void) => void, options?: Bluebird.PromisifyOptions): (arg1: A1) => Bluebird<T>;
  static promisify<T, A1, A2>(func: (arg1: A1, arg2: A2, callback: (err: any, result: T) => void) => void, options?: Bluebird.PromisifyOptions): (arg1: A1, arg2: A2) => Bluebird<T>;
  static promisify<T, A1, A2, A3>(func: (arg1: A1, arg2: A2, arg3: A3, callback: (err: any, result: T) => void) => void, options?: Bluebird.PromisifyOptions): (arg1: A1, arg2: A2, arg3: A3) => Bluebird<T>;
  static promisify<T, A1, A2, A3, A4>(func: (arg1: A1, arg2: A2, arg3: A3, arg4: A4, callback: (err: any, result: T) => void) => void, options?: Bluebird.PromisifyOptions): (arg1: A1, arg2: A2, arg3: A3, arg4: A4) => Bluebird<T>;
  static promisify<T, A1, A2, A3, A4, A5>(func: (arg1: A1, arg2: A2, arg3: A3, arg4: A4, arg5: A5, callback: (err: any, result: T) => void) => void, options?: Bluebird.PromisifyOptions): (arg1: A1, arg2: A2, arg3: A3, arg4: A4, arg5: A5) => Bluebird<T>;
```

Answer (score 1):

In cases where the type system fails to infer the promisified function signature, you can provide type hints using generics:

```ts
import { promisify } from 'util';
import jsonwebtoken from 'jsonwebtoken';
import type { VerifyOptions, Secret } from 'jsonwebtoken';


const verify = promisify<string, Secret, VerifyOptions | undefined, JwtExtendedPayload>(jsonwebtoken.verify);
```

which would yield the result below:

```ts
const verify: (arg1: string, arg2: jsonwebtoken.Secret, arg3: jsonwebtoken.VerifyOptions | undefined) => Promise<JwtExtendedPayload>
```